# Can JAXB unmarshall XML according to my object structure?

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

My object structure is not hugely different from XML structure. Just want to change it for one element.
I have an XML structure like this

```
<Parent>
    <Child1></Child1>
    <Child2></Child2>
    <Child3></Child3>
    <Child3></Child3>
    <Child3></Child3>
</Parent>
```

and its equivalent JAXB class looks like this

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="Parent")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "Parent_Type")
    public class Parent {
        protected List<Child1Type> child1;
        protected List<Child2Type> child2;
        protected List<Child3Type> child3;
    }
```

But as per the database model requirement I want Child3 list under Child1. This will help me to save XML using Hibernate.

```
public class Child1 {
    protected List<Child3Type> child3;
}
```

How can I configure it with JAXB?
Or should I use `afterUnmarshal` to manually do it?

Comment: You may be interested in `@XmlIDREF`:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I have just update the expected object model. Here Child1 needs the List of Child3.Sorry for the copy-paste mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible for my requirement. I have written a transform logic under afterUnmarshal() method to convert regular unmarshal to transform as per my need.